# Why are `\Q` `\E` in a Perl pattern in some cases interpreted as literal `Q` `E`?

Tags: regex, perl

If `'` is the delimiter, or if interpolated from a variable, the regular expression `\QW\ER` matches `QWER` and not `WR` (observed with v5.6.2, v5.10.1 and v5.18.2 of Perl and at http://www.perlfect.com/articles/regextutor.shtml), i. e., `\Q` `\E` in the pattern are not interpreted as a quoting escape, but as literal `Q` `E`.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$re = '\QW\ER';
print '$re = ', $re, "\n";
while (<DATA>)
{
    print qw(/\QW\ER/), "  matches ", $_ if /\QW\ER/;
    print qw(m'\QW\ER'), " matches ", $_ if m'\QW\ER';
    print qw(/$re/), "     matches ", $_ if /$re/;
}
__DATA__
QWERT
WRONG
```

Output:

```
$re = \QW\ER
m'\QW\ER' matches QWERT
/$re/     matches QWERT
/\QW\ER/  matches WRONG
```

(Only the last line is what I had expected.)

Is this a bug? ... a feature? ... documented anywhere?

Comment: @Armali, how do you test it? Can you show the code and the output?

Comment: @choroba: How did you observe that it works okay in v5.14.2?

Comment: `perl -E 'say /(?<=\QW\E)R/ for qw( QWERT WRONG )'`, returns an empty line and 1.

Comment: [Understand the order of operations in double quoted contexts](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2012/01/understand-the-order-of-operations-in-double-quoted-contexts/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the explanation in the Perl Language reference, section perlop:

> The following escape sequences are available in constructs that
>   interpolate, ...

```
\Q          quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till \E or
            end of string
\E          end either case modification or quoted section
            (whichever was last seen)
```

Since `'\QW\ER'` is a construct where the delimiter is `'` `'`, which provides no interpolating, `\Q` `\E` are not available as a quoting escape here.

Answer (score 6):

You may be observing this if you are using a string with escapes to define a regex:

```
# don't use strings if you have escapes:
#  my $re = '(?<=\QW\E)R';
my $re = qr/(?<=\QW\E)R/;
/($re)/ and print "$_: $1\n" for qw(QWERT WRONG);
```

Comment: Using `qr` shows the expected behaviour because the `\Q` `\E` are thereby removed from the RE, which you can see if you print $re; so, this doesn't say anything about actually using `\Q` `\E` in the lookbehind pattern.